# How to restore CC Files for geometry dash?

Tags: geometry-dash

Today my geometry dash wasn't turning on. I found a Youtube video to delete CC files in local geometry dash, but it said to only delete the 2 and I wasn't paying attention. I deleted both of them it still didn't work. I found an app called GD Fix App hoping it would fix all the problems that were in the CC Files and it said didn't find any CC files

Does anybody know how to bring back the CC files?

Comment: Im sorry i deleted 5 files

Comment: The question and format was a mess, so I cleaned it up the best I could. Please let me know if I misinterpreted anything